# Android Studio java.io.FileNotFoundException while using a web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-studio, yii

I am newbie to native android development. I am using `android studio` for my app development. I have created a `DB` with two tables in it, and then i have created a `webservice` using `Yii`. Below is my DB TABLE

[image]

Now i want is to make an app in which when a user enters an `id` the corresponding `username` should be shown to the user. For this i have done the followings

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String URLGET = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/app/web/users/";
String result = "";
TextView getData;
EditText userInput;
public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    getData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getData);
    userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterId);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Submit);


    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String reqURL = URLGET;

            new RestOperation().execute(reqURL);
            //callWebService(query);
        }
    });

}

public class RestOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


    final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String content;
    String error;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    String data = "";

   // TextView getData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getData);
   // EditText userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterId);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        try {
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "-" + userInput.getText();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);


            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.flush();

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));


            }

            content = sb.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(br != null)
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if (error != null) {
            getData.setText("Error" + error);
        } else {
            getData.setText(content);


        }
    }
}}
```

For now i am running my app on emulator, so that's why i am using `10.0.2.2`. But when i run my app i get the following error

[image]

While in `logcat` i get the bellow warning

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:8000/app/web/users/
02-07 18:27:35.553 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err: at  com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
02-07 18:27:35.553 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err:     at com.example.accurat.webservice.MainActivity$RestOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:121)
02-07 18:27:35.553 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err:     at com.example.accurat.webservice.MainActivity$RestOperation.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75)
02-07 18:27:35.553 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
02-07 18:27:35.553 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-07 18:27:35.554 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-07 18:27:35.554 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-07 18:27:35.554 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-07 18:27:35.554 14687-14757/com.example.accurat.webservice W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have also used `localhost` and `my ip` in the `URL` but all i got the error like below

[image]

I am stuck to it from the day and really don't know what to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which catch/exception is triggered? `error = e.getMessage();`. You will not know which one unless you change to `error = "IOException:  " + e.getMessage();`. Adapt the other too. And tell us.

Comment: `final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();`. Please remove not used code. It's confusing.

Comment: `data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "-" + userInput.getText();`. Only for a second key=value pair you need to add an '&'. And you url encode the wrong string. And it is 'key=' and not 'key-'. Better: `data = "data=" +  URLEncoder.encode(userInput.getText());`

Comment: You probably have to add `connection.setMethod("POST")`.

Comment: @greenapps the second catch exception is triggered. What to add in place of `final HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();` ? 
I am using `GET` method so why to use `POST`?

Comment: You have to connect your local network instead of internet.

Comment: already tried `localhost` but result is same

Comment: For possible misundertanding, i didn't mean that change URLGET value. I said your device have to connect your computer.

Comment: @onrgns I am using emulator for testing my app not the device but if there is any way that i can connect my `device` locally so please share it